# Can't configure quota on CentOS 5.5. Strange behaviour of quotacheck and other quota commands

Tags: linux, centos, ext4, quota

I have Centos 5.5 linux with quota enabled in fstab

---

[root@drone3 ~]# mount  | grep usrquota

/dev/sda4 on /storage type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,usrquota)

---

When I tray to activate quota on the /storage I hit the following messages :

---

[root@drone3 ~]# quotacheck -cu /storage

quotacheck: Mountpoint (or device) /storage not found.

quotacheck: Can't find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.

[root@drone3 ~]# uname -a

Linux drone3.xxxxxxxxxxx.com 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Nov 9 12:54:20 EST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

As a result no aquota.user file is created on /storage and quota is not enabled/started. 
What do you think - where is the problem? Is it because of ext4 file system and/or this is a bug ? I did not found anything related to these messages and ext4 in google. 
All Quota related commands give similar messages - mount point is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=500231